# Kofax integration with Nuxeo

Tags: nuxeo, kofax

I'm working with Nuxeo 7.10.

Now I'm facing with problem of integration Kofax with it.I have seen Kofax is integrated with Alfresco but with Nuxeo I didn't find any thing.

Have any body any idea, if it is possible, how can I integrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to clarify which Kofax you want to integrate. As for Kofax Capture, there's no dedicated Export Connector for Nuxeo, however Kofax does [offer a connector](https://services.kofax.com/support/products/export-connectors/) for anything that complies with the CMIS standard, which [Nuxeo should](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/cmis/).

Kofax TotalAgility on the other hand offers a dedicated CMIS activity that (among others) allows you to get, update or find a document in any compliant EDMS (hence, Nuxeo).

Comment: Communication with CMIS is the point, for  Nuxeo thers's no Connector. I want to export scanned document from Kofax to the Nuxeo Repository. Yet i didn't find any solution do do this. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Export Connector for Kofax Capture.
There is a frame work you can use that integrates the Kofax API.
Nuxeo has an REST API i see so that is no problem.
Just write a Export Connector that exposes the REST API.

When you are going to write an export connector for version 10.0 en below you have to consider that Kofax is COM based after version 10.0 Kofax is .Net based.